# How can I write a gradle build task that runs a script such as "npm install" in a different directory than my gradle build file?

Tags: gradle, npm, kotlin

In a single project, I have two folders, `project/server` and `project/web`.

`project/server` is the root of my spring boot app with my `build.gradle.kts` file, while `project/web` is a react app with my `package.json` scripts, such as `npm start`. I would like to make a custom gradle task that runs "npm install" and "npm start" in the `project/server` folder, but I'm having trouble writing this task.

I have been following: https://karl.run/2018/05/07/kotlin-spring-boot-react/ and am getting tripped up at the part of the tutorial that says to run:

```
// Task for installing frontend dependencies in web
task installDependencies(type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['install']
    execOverrides {
        it.workingDir = '../web'
    }
}

// Task for executing build:gradle in web
task buildWeb(type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['run', 'build:gradle']
    execOverrides {
        it.workingDir = '../web'
    }
}

// Before buildWeb can run, installDependencies must run
buildWeb.dependsOn installDependencies

// Before build can run, buildWeb must run
build.dependsOn buildWeb
```

I can't use these snippets as they aren't getting recognized with Kotlin.

Comment: To clarify, the Groovy scripts work properly but your problem is converting the Groovy to Kotlin, correct?

Comment: Hey @Slaw, I cannot confirm whether these script work or not, but yes my main question would be how would I get this to converted correctly to Kotlin. Thanks for your question!

Answer (score 4):

This is the script converted to Kotlin DSL:

```
import com.moowork.gradle.node.npm.NpmTask

// Task for installing frontend dependencies in web
val installDependencies by tasks.registering(NpmTask::class) {
    setArgs(listOf("install"))
    setExecOverrides(closureOf<ExecSpec> {
        setWorkingDir("../web")
    })
}

// Task for executing build:gradle in web
val buildWeb by tasks.registering(NpmTask::class) {
    // Before buildWeb can run, installDependencies must run
    dependsOn(installDependencies)

    setArgs(listOf("run", "build:gradle"))
    setExecOverrides(closureOf<ExecSpec> {
        setWorkingDir("../web")
    })
}

// Before build can run, buildWeb must run
tasks.build {
    dependsOn(buildWeb)
}
```